# Являются ли слова «туш» и «тушь» паронимами?

Tags: лексика, паронимы, лексикология

Согласно определению, паронимы — это слова, сходные по звучанию и морфемному составу, но различающиеся лексическим значением.

В словах «туш» и «тушь» похожий морфемный состав: они состоят только из корня и окончания, они сходны по звучанию, но различны по значению.

Они также попадают под определение фонетических омонимов. То есть они одновременно и омофоны, и паронимы?

Answer (score 4):

Тушь и туш — это не паронимы, хотя они звучат одинаково и имеют сходное написание. Паронимы обычно являются однокоренными словами, а разное значение им придают другие морфемы.

Паро́нимы (от др.-греч. παρα- — приставка со значением смежности, ὄνομα — «имя») — это слова, сходные **по звучанию и морфемному составу**, но различающиеся лексическим значением. В данном случае корни этих слов не имеют ничего общего.

1) **ТУШ**, -а; м. [нем. Tusсh] Короткая музыкальная пьеса, исполняемая в торжественных случаях (при чествовании, приветствиях, вручении наград и т.п.), большей частью на духовых

I, муз. Из нем. Тusсh — то же, о котором см. Брюкнер 585 II «кувшин», вологодск. (Даль). Возм., из мар. tujǝs, **tüś «сосуд из бересты»**. Далее см. ту́ес.

2) **ТУШЬ**, -и; ж. [нем. Tusche] 1. Чёрная или цветная водяная краска специального приготовления (употребляется для черчения, рисования, письма). Обвести чертёж тушью. Перья для туши. Штрихи тушью. Разбавить т.инструментах.

тушь Заимств. в XVIII в. из нем. яз., где Tusche < франц. touche, — производного **от toucher «касаться».** Развитие значений: «тушь» < «то, чем накладывают тени, штрихи» < «касание» (при тушевке). Школьный этимологический словарь русского языка. Происхождение слов. — М.: Дрофа Н. М. Шанский, Т. А. Боброва 2004

Comment: Так а что имеется в виду под сходным морфемным составом? Я говорю: оба слова состоят из корня (и окончания), их морфемный состав количественно сходен. В определении не говорится об однокоренных словах.

Comment: Да, я знаком с припиской, что они «обычно однокоренные». Но ведь «обычно», а не «всегда»...

Comment: Чаще всего это однокоренные слова с разными суффиксами. Другой вариант - это развитие значения слова по смежности. Другими словами, должно быть общее исходное слово с общим значением. Главное свойство паронимов - это  то, что они кажутся синонимами, но таковыми не являются. К паронимам не относят слова, если их значения не имеют ничего общего, даже если их звуковая форма одинакова. Тогда это омофоны.

Comment: это как раз то, что меня интересовало. Не дадите ссылку на источник, который подтвердит, что между паронимами должна существовать какая-либо связь значений?

Comment: В Википедии рассматриваются разные виды паронимов, и оказывается есть КОРНЕВЫЕ паронимы, которые сходны чисто случайно: эскалатор и экскаватор. Я уже думаю, на назвать ли ваши слова графическими паронимами.https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Паронимы

Comment: ну вот. В Вики в статьях про паронимию и омонимию бардак, по-моему.

Comment: Бельчиков выделяет две группы паронимов: явно однокоренные и  неявные. Можно посмотреть во вступительной статье к его словарю http://padaread.com/?book=183123&pg=7

Comment: то есть вы все равно не согласны, что *туш* и *тушь* паронимы?

Comment: По Бельчикову это не паронимы, потому что неявной связи тоже нет, а она должна быть как-то выявлена и обозначена. У этих же слов (название растения и глагол касаться) такую общую  основу вряд ли можно найти.

Comment: Простите, но, кажется, Вы _очень_ спешили.  Из Вашего ответа: 1) _I, муз_ —  что-то пропущено? 2) _Разбавить т.инструментах_ — ?

Answer (score 1):

См. [**Розенталь Д. Э., Теленкова М. А. "Словарь-справочник лингвистических терминов"**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/lingvistic/1053):

> **паронимы**
>
> **...Однокоренные
>   слова**, близкие по звучанию, но разные по значению или частично
>   совпадающие в своем значении. *Ароматный — ароматический —
>   ароматичный; банковский — банковый; встать — стать...*
>
> **Некоторые исследователи к паронимам относят также разнокоренные слова, близкие по звучанию и вследствие этого допускающие смешение в
>   речи.** *Кампания — компания* (омофоны), *экскаватор — эскалатор*.

В  "Учебном словаре паронимов русского языка" (авторы -- ВВЕДЕНСКАЯ ЛЮДМИЛА АЛЕКСЕЕВНА, КОЛЕСНИКОВ НИКОЛАЙ ПАВЛОВИЧ) говорится, что при "узком" понимании паронимов к ним относят только однокоренные слова. Если же

> ...явление паронимии понимать шире, то к паронимам должны быть
>   отнесены не только однокоренные, но и разнокоренные (их гораздо
>   меньше) слова, в какой-то мере сходные по звучанию и смешиваемые в
>   речи. При таком понимании паронимами будут и и такие пары слов, как
>   *боцман* и *лоцман, локаут* и *нокаут, агат* и *гагат, трепан* и *трепанг, олифа* и *олива, давить* и *довлеть* и др.

Авторы этого словаря придерживаются именно "широкого" понимания паронимии.

> Являются ли слова «туш» и «тушь» паронимами?

Эти слова паронимами не признаются даже словаристами, "широко" понимающими  паронимию.

Из "Словаря паронимов русского языка" Н.П. Колесникова, изданного в 1971 году:

> Не являются паронимами и потому не включаются в "Словарь" такие пары
>   слов, которые вступают в омонимические отношения: *коса*
>   (сельскохозяйственное орудие) и *коса* (сплетённые волосы)… Не
>   включаются в "Словарь" и слова, различающиеся написанием, но звучащие
>   одинаково (омоформы): ***туш*** и ***тушь***, *ангидрид* и
>   *ангидрит*...

Что же до пары слов *лагуна — лакуна*, упомянутых в комментарии в этой теме… Эти слова в словаре Колесникова считаются паронимами. См.:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но всё же большинство лингвистов под паронимами понимают лишь однокоренные слова.

Comment: Так можно считать *тушь — туш*, *лагуна — лакуна* и т. д. паронимами?

Comment: Ну, это смотря каким определением слова _паронимы_ пользоваться... Если относить к паронимам и "разнокоренные слова, близкие по звучанию и вследствие этого допускающие смешение в речи" (см. выше) -- то да, паронимы.

Comment: благодарю за мнение!

Comment: Всё зависит от того, насколько "некоторые исследователи" авторитетны, а это определяется по близости к академической науке вообще и к данной теме в частности.

Comment: _Arina: "Всё зависит от того, насколько "некоторые исследователи" авторитетны, а это определяется по близости к академической науке..."_ === Аrina, Вы, наверное, не обратили внимание: на "некоторых исследователей" ссылался не я, а Розенталь. Вас или меня, далёких от _академической науки_, он явно не имел в виду. И сам он считал, что лучше к паронимам относить только однокоренные слова. Но тем не менее -- и другое понимание термина _паронимы_ существует, о чём Розенталь и сказал в своём словаре.

Comment: _@Aer: Так можно считать тушь — туш, лагуна — лакуна и т. д. паронимами?_ ===  Aer, я сегодня вечером вернусь к этому вопросу, а пока свой ответ удалю.